# Cordova Jquery not posting CSP

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I know this question has been ask but I have trid all the solutions I saw on here but am frustrated my app isnt posting to my server site its a Cordova no phone gap 4.1.1 version.
First told me error about Content-Security-Policy I try change the meta tag but it seem to not post to my local server if load this file in the browser it post to my server can some one assist an give me clue why this whitelist plugin is giving so much trouble?

```
$("#insert").click(function(){
        var title=$("#title").val();
        var duration=$("#duration").val();
        var price=$("#price").val();
        var dataString="title="+title+"&duration="+duration+"&price="+price+"&insert=";

            alert(price);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",

                url:"http://localhost/mainfolder/app/public/routename/",
                data: dataString,
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(){ $("#insert").val('Connecting...');},
                success: function(data){
                    if(data=="ok")
                    {
                        alert("inserted");
                        $("#insert").val('Insert');
                    }
                    else if(data=="error")
                    {
                        alert("error");
                         $("#insert").val('Insert');
                    }
                }
            });
```

I am using laravel on the server side
my meta tag

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
default-src *; 
style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; 
script-src * 'unsafe-inline'; 
media-src *; img-src * data:; 
" />
```

I have tried

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
default-src *; 
style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; 
script-src * 'unsafe-inline'; 
media-src *; img-src * data:; 
 content-src http://localhost:*" />
```

also
     http://localhost/" />

final tried

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

But none work also the above script is inline my index.html

Comment: Did you added the following in your config.xml, <allow-intent href="http://*/*" /> 
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" /> 
<allow-intent href="tel:*" /> 
<allow-intent href="sms:*" /> 
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" /> 
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />

Comment: yes it comes witht the cordova version am using see @Gandhi <code>   <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

Comment: try using the machine IP instead of localhost. It should work I feel

Comment: Where would I place for I did so in the meta tag an got no response for e.g http://127.4.2.1 thats what i added where you see localhost

Comment: change the ajax URL to IP from localhost